# Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a problem, because I try to start my first program in Eclipse with selenium. Parameters: selenium = 2.49.1, firefox 50.1. or antivirus Kaspersky can block anything? Do I have incorrect configuration of firefox selenium - are incompatible?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Login {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
//  LoginTest lt = new LoginTest();

    WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
    wd.get("http://www.facebook.com");
    wd.manage().window().maximize();
//  lt.setUp();
//  lt.test();
//  lt.tearDown();

}
```

Log

```
Build info: version: '2.49.1', revision: '7203e46', time: '2016-01-21 17:35:35'
System info: host: 'Damian', ip: 'xxx.xxx.x.xxx', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at loginTest.Login.main(Login.java:13)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
"homepageURL":null},{"locales":["vi"],"name":"Kaspersky Protection","description":"BaĚ‰o vĂŞĚŁ baĚŁn trĂŞn Internet vĆˇĚ?i phĂ˘Ě€n mĆˇĚ‰ rĂ´ĚŁng tĆ°Ě€ Kaspersky Lab","creator":null,"homepageURL":null},{"locales":["zh-Hans"],"name":"ĺŤˇĺ·´ć–ŻĺźşäżťćŠ¤","description":"ä˝żç”¨ĺŤˇĺ·´ć–Żĺźşĺ®žéŞŚĺ®¤çš„ć‰©ĺ±•ĺŠźč?˝ĺŻąć‚¨çš„äş’č?”ç˝‘çš„äżťćŠ¤ă€‚","creator":null,"homepageURL":null},{"locales":["zh-Hans-CN"],"name":"ĺŤˇĺ·´ć–ŻĺźşäżťćŠ¤","description":"ä˝żç”¨ĺŤˇĺ·´ć–Żĺźşĺ®žéŞŚĺ®¤çš„ć‰©ĺ±•ĺŠźč?˝ĺŻąć‚¨çš„äş’č?”ç˝‘çš„äżťćŠ¤ă€‚","creator":null,"homepageURL":null}],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"38.0a1","maxVersion":"43.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":2,"seen":true}
1483108475424   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1483108475425   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1483108475425   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1483108475430   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1483108475439   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1483108475441   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on aushelper@mozilla.org version 1.0
1483108475444   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1483108475447   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.5
1483108475447   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1483108475450   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.5
1483108475452   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1483108475454   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.0
1483108475459   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1483108475459   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1483108475459   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1483108475459   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1483108475460   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1483108475461   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1483108475488   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1483108475489   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1483108475489   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1483108475490   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1483108475490   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1483108475491   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1483108480573   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1483108480574   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1483108480575   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1483108482886   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1483108482886   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1483108482886   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1483108482915   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1483108482940   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1483108482941   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1483108482972   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1483108484196   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1483108484196   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1483108484197   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1483108484207   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1483108484239   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1483108484933   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
    ... 7 more
```

Maybe someone knows how to help? I already spend a lot of time on this problem, and it can easy problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Antivirus is blocking your connection. Try turning it off.

Also if you're running Firefox version 47+ you need to run Selenium 3 (looks like you have Selenium 2.49.1) as Firefox uses their own `geckodriver` after version 47 and above.

Comment: That second part is only half true. You do need to use geckodriver with Firefox 47+, but you do not need Selenium 3 for that. Geckodriver has been included with Selenium 2.x for a while. I'm using it with 2.53.1. Either way, you need to change your code to use the new driver.